# `type` synonym with phantom allowed no warnings?

Tags: haskell, phantom-types, type-synonyms

```
data D a b = MkD a
```

`b` is called a 'phantom type', because it doesn't appear on RHS of `=`. That's useful for type-level tagging of the data.

```
type T a b = Maybe a
```

(GHC doesn't complain, even with `:set -Wall`.) `b` is a what? And what could it be useful for?

I feel GHC should warn me `b` is not used on RHS.

Comment: Ha, somebody spotted this/raised an issue 3 years ago https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/15687

Comment: "Somebody"?  Wasn't that you?